# A table not mapped in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I put the question before but as i'm new with the site i found problems writing my question. Well. I'm working on two projects: Create an EJB project and a webapp. In both i have to store information from the webapp into a database. The first one has worked. In the seconde, i am getting this error

```
ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8180-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ENIT for method public abstract java.util.List metier.sessions.EnitLocal.consulterProf(): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Enseignants is not mapped [Select coount(p) from Enseignants p ]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at metier.sessions.EnitLocal$$$view1.consulterProf(Unknown Source) [EnitEJB.jar:]
at Servlets.Controleur.doPost(Controleur.java:58)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Enseignants is not mapped [Select coount(p) from Enseignants p ]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1348) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:288) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:425) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at metier.sessions.EnitImpl.consulterProf(EnitImpl.java:49) [EnitEJB.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 35 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Enseignants is not mapped [Select coount(p) from Enseignants p ]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3252) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3141) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:694) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:550) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:235) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:285) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
... 56 more mapped
```

Here is a part of my classes

```
@Stateless(name = "ENIT")
public class EnitImpl implements EnitLocal {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "tp3")
private EntityManager em  ;
public EnitImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void addCours(Cours cour) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    em.merge(cour);
}
public List<Cours> consulterCours() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Query req = em.createQuery("Select c from cours c ");
    return req.getResultList();
}
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Cours consulter(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cours cours = em.find(Cours.class, id);
    if (cours == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Cours inexistant");
    return cours;
}
public void addProf(Enseignant E) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    em.merge(E);
}
public List<Enseignant> consulterProf() {
    Query req = em.createQuery("Select p from enseignants p ");
    return req.getResultList();
}
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Enseignant consulterP(int id) {
    Enseignant E = em.find(Enseignant.class, id);
    if (E == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Enseignant non trouvé");
    return E;
}
}
```

And the interface:

```
@Local
public interface EnitLocal {
public void addProf(Enseignant E);
public List<Enseignant> consulterProf();
public Enseignant consulterP(int id);
public void addCours(Cours C);
public List<Cours> consulterCours();
public Cours consulter(int id);
}
```

When I debug the program, em is null. I was using `em.persist()` but it didn't work. So i've used `em.merge()`. The diffrence between this project and the old one is that here I've this join 'ManyToOne'.
Can someone see the problem?

A part of the class Enseignants:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Enseignants")
 public class Enseignant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private int id_int; 
public Enseignant() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Enseignant(int id_int, String nom, String prenom, String grade) {
    super();
    this.id_int = id_int;
    Nom = nom;
    Prenom = prenom;
    Grade = grade;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Enseignant [id_int=" + id_int + ", Nom=" + Nom + ", Prenom="
            + Prenom + ", Grade=" + Grade + "]";
}
public int getId_int() {
    return id_int;
}
public void setId_int(int id_int) {
    this.id_int = id_int;
}
public String getNom() {
    return Nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    Nom = nom;
}
public String getPrenom() {
    return Prenom;
}
public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    Prenom = prenom;
}
public String getGrade() {
    return Grade;
}
public void setGrade(String grade) {
    Grade = grade;
}
public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}
@Column (name="Nom")
private String Nom; 
@Column (name="Prenom")
private String Prenom; 
@Column (name="Grade")
private String Grade;
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking why you get the exception? If so, post the complete stack trace. Are you asking why em is null? How can you call methods on it if it's null? Are you asking why persist() didn't work? If so, post the relevant code, explain what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Well, this is my whole stack:

Comment: Well, this is my whole stack (edited)..  I'd love to know why it is not mapped when everythg seem ok.. And If is it possible to identify why persist didn't work? Or why em is empty.. Btw, when i call for the method `consulterP(int id)` it works.. I cannot identify where the problem is exactly otherwise i would have not posted my question

Comment: Your query is "Select coount(p) from Enseignants p". And the error is "Enseignants is not mapped". `coount` is obviously invalid, and your entity is not named `Enseignants`. It's named `Enseignant`.

Comment: Well, it is not the problem. This is another try. I was just using "Select p from Enseignants p" and i'm getting the same problem.. with count, the same problem also. And the name of the table is "Enseignants" with 's'

Comment: Hey @JBNizet .. You were right.. It has worked.. Thank you so much.. Excuse me i am making my first steps.. I thought that i put the table name just like it is in the database. Learnt s.thg at least. (excuse my english, it's the 4th language i ve learnt)